# In Powershell script to remove XML nodes that match a certain text

Tags: xml, powershell

````
```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TrdData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn">
<BHDRY><AppBHDRY xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn" xsi:schemaLocation="urn"><Fr><OrgId><Id><OrgId><Othr><Id>2138001WXZQOPMPA3D50</Id><SchmeNm><PTTYD>OK</PTTYD></SchmeNm></Othr></OrgId></Id></OrgId></Fr>
<To><OrgId><Id><OrgId><Othr><Id>LG</Id><SchmeNm><PTTYD>Author</PTTYD></SchmeNm></Othr></OrgId></Id></OrgId></To><BizMsgIdr>transactions</BizMsgIdr><MsgDefIdr>aut</MsgDefIdr><CreDt>2019-12-13T07:13:20.583Z</CreDt></AppBHDRY></BHDRY>
<LOPY><Document xmlns="urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn">
<FIMRptgTxRpt><Tx>
<New><TxId>ANB20191212z</TxId><EPty>549300WOIFUSNYH0FL22</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>ANB20191212y</TxId><EPty>W85O53OGKS</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>XYZ20191212s</TxId><EPty>JHE42UYNWW</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>XYZ20191212r</TxId><EPty>529900SEO5</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>ABN20191212u</TxId><EPty>JHE42UYNWW</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>ABN20191212</TxId><EPty>353800CTPL</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
<New><TxId>XYZ20191212</TxId><EPty>353800V64</EPty><IPtyInd>false</IPtyInd><SgPty>WXZQOPMPXCVFDS</SgPty></New></Tx><Tx>
</FIMRptgTxRpt></Document></LOPY></TrdData>
```
````

I have searched and searched to find an easy why to remove nodes that match certain chars in the begining of the TXID. For example I would like to remove all nodes that match **XYZ**.  I have tried the following code:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $myXMLPath)
 $totalRecords = 
 $xmlDoc.ChildNodes.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx.New.count -1
 $recordCount = 0
$removeCode = 'XYZ'

while ($recordCount -ne $totalRecords) {
   $check = $xmlDoc.ChildNodes.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx.New[$recordCount].TxId.Contains($removeCode)

if($check){
```

$xmlDoc.ChildNodes.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx.New[$recordCount].RemoveChild 
        }

```
    $recordCount +=1

}
$xmlDoc.ChildNodes.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx.New
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional logic (`Where-Object`) to select the nodes you want to delete and then utilize the `RemoveChild()` method of the selected nodes' parent objects (`.ParentNode`). The code below will remove the `New` nodes that match your condition.

```
$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $myXMLPath)
$xmlDoc.TrdData.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx.New |
    Where TxId -match '^XYZ' |
        Foreach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```

The code below will remove the `Tx` nodes that match your condition:

```
$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $myXMLPath)
    $xmlDoc.TrdData.LOPY.Document.FIMRptgTxRpt.Tx |
        Where {$_.New.TxId -match '^XYZ' } |
            Foreach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to remove, you may need to play with what AdminOfThings has here.  for instance, if you drill all the way down to New, you'll leave the Tx tags that contain that record, which may or may not be desired.  Also, you'll need to remember to do a $xmlDoc.Save($myXMLPath) afterwards for the document to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thank you very much your quick reply. Only issue is that with a larger sample of data, this leaves behind empty child nodes:         <Tx>
        </Tx>
        <Tx>
        </Tx>
        <Tx>
        </Tx>
        <Tx>
        </Tx>
        <Tx>
        </Tx>

Comment: @Tesh I added another code snippet for the Tx nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat, sorry I do not have the reputation to like your answers.  Cheers.